# Unity3D Prefab with UI button stopped working

Tags: unity-game-engine

We dynamically create a new prefab which contains a number of text controls and a button. The button stopped being clickable when created dynamically. If I run in the editor, and get to the point where the button is displayed, clicking it doesn't do anything. If I drop a new prefab on the canvas while the game is running, and click the button, it works fine. I noticed this same behavior with another prefab. All of the static buttons work fine.

I also checked to make sure that the prefab is the last (bottom) item on the canvas - the top most object. Although it seems as if it's behind another object.

To further test while its running in the editor, I clicked on the EventSystem in the editor and then clicked on the button in the Game scene. In the inspector it shows no object selected and moving the mouse shows pointerEnter: BackgroundImage.

If I drop the same prefab during design time and run the game, the button works fine.

I think this started to happen after we upgraded to 2017.1.0f3.
Here's an example of one of the prefab we create.

```
var eofl = Instantiate(endOfLevelTemplate, GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform, false) as GameObject;
```

**Update**
I had left out some information which turns out to be the possible cause but I don't know why.
After creating the object I set the scale to 0 and then use LeanTween to scale it up to 1.

```
eofl.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0);
LeanTween.scale(eofl, new Vector3(1, 1), .5f).setOnComplete(EndOfLevelScalingComplete, eofl);
```

I tried to comment out these 2 lines and that seems to have made it work again. 
I don't know why this would all of a sudden stop working. I upgraded to the latest LeanTween as well but not change.

Comment: instead of setting it to scale 0, set it to scale 0.01, that should work

Comment: I tried setting the scale to 0.1 but I still get the issue. Changing the effect to alpha 0 -> 1 works. I'm going to still try and figure out the scaling issue though.